Is there a way to create pdf like form layout in flutter?
I am wondering if I can make a text layout like this:

The colons are aligned with each other, and so are the values. I tried using a fixed-width container with space between rows as a child but the value part is not aligned, any idea guys?
Column(
 children: [
  Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4
   child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
     Text('Jenis Layanan'),
     Text(':')
    ],
   ),
  ),
 ],
)

sorry I realized that you really meant colons.

Try to wrapping Text with fixed width Container along with the Row for all 3 Texts.

Yes you can. I personally use Table for this case.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  /// Table row widget
  TableRow buildTableRow(String title, String value) {
    return TableRow(
      children: [
        // This widget is for the value of first column
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 4, 8, 4),
          child: Text(
            title,
          ),
        ),
        // This widget is for the value of second column
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
          child: Text(': $value'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          // Creating table
          child: Table(
            // The [columnWidths] value must be equal with the total column of [buildTableRow]
            columnWidths: const {
              // Creates the first column width based on intrinsic sizing.
              // 
              // This [IntrinsicColumnWidth()] is expensive, so don't use it too often.
              0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
              // The second column take all the remaining space.
              1: FlexColumnWidth(),
            },
            // This is where to put the [TableRow]
            children: [
              buildTableRow('Jenis Layanan', 'Tarik Tunai'),
              buildTableRow('Bank Tujuan', 'BRI'),
              buildTableRow('No Rekening', '0129319201'),
              buildTableRow('Nama Pemilik Rekening', 'Adam'),
              buildTableRow('Nominal', 'Rp. 10.000'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And this is the output:


This is the way to go! But I just wanted to add that you can also use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_layout_grid which also has some more settings to fine-tune.
